# TypeScript better way to encapsulate type definitions than namespace?

Tags: typescript, types, namespaces, typescript-typings

So far for this project I've been using namespace to organize my types. So for example, I would do something like this:

```
namespace FooBar {
   export interface Foo {
       Biz: HelperType
   }
   export interface Bar {
      // blah
   }

   type HelperType = 'uWu'
}
```

This way types that I don't want to be accessible elsewhere are private, and I can organize related types together. Is using Namespaces the best approach for something like this? Or is there something else that I should look into?

Comment: Namespaces aren't great, you'd be better with imports/exports.